# Choosing method on button click

Tags: java, android

I have tested the methods individually by calling them in the case which evaluates the equals button. They work fine. My issue is determining whether the multiplication or addition operator was pressed, and then calling the appropriate method.

I searched online and used an if statement within the case which evaluates the multiplication as such:

```
case R.id.buttonequals:
    if (v.equals(btnmult)) {
        Multiplication();
    }

    else if (v.equals(btnplus)) {
        Addition();
    }
        break;
```

This doesn't work. It seems logical enough. If the equal button is pressed, then depending on what was pushed, the right method will be called. My full code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// variables declared to hold buttons and text field.
Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btnc,
    btnplus, btnd, btnpnt, btnequal, btnmult;
TextView text;
int num1, num2;
String input;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// reference and assign the resources for the view elements
btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
btnc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonc);
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
btnd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondel);
btnpnt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonpnt);
btnplus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplus);
btnequal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonequal);
btnmult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonmult);

// add the click listeners
btn0.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn4.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn5.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn6.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn7.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn8.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btn9.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnc.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnd.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnpnt.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnplus.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnequal.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
btnmult.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}



private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button0:

        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn0.getText().toString());

        break;

    case R.id.button1:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn1.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn2.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn3.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn4.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button5:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn5.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button6:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn6.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button7:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn7.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button8:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn8.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.button9:
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()
                + btn9.getText().toString());
        break;

    case R.id.buttondel:
        String contents = text.getText().toString();

        if (contents.length() > 1) {
            text.setText(contents.substring(0, contents.length() - 1));
        } else {
            text.setText("");
        }

        break;

    case R.id.buttonc:
        text.setText("");
        break;

    case R.id.button8:
        String dot = ".";
        String concat = text.getText() + dot;
        text.setText(concat);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonplus:

        num1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        text.setText(text.getText() + "+");
        break;

    case R.id.buttonmult:
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        text.setText(text.getText() + "x");
        break;

    case R.id.buttonequals:
    if (v.equals(btnmult)) {
        Multiplication();
    }

    else if (v.equals(btnplus)) {
        Addition();
    }
        break;

    }
}

};

public void Addition() {
text.setText("");
int total = num1 + num2;
text.setText(Integer.toString(total));

}

public void Multiplication() {
text.setText("");
int total = num1 * num2;
text.setText(Integer.toString(total));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologise if the solution is blindly obvious. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: is v the View clicked?

Comment: Hey Atul, it is yeah :)

Comment: then u will not b able to test it ;) coz when the user click = button the v will be R.id.buttonequals. For your case you can have flags say boolean multiply = false. On click of multiply button set flag to true then in your case R.id.buttonequals: do if (multiply) then your method. Similarly for divide.

Comment: Atul you ARE SIMPLY AMAZING, i'll remember this solution in the future!

Comment: Add your solution in the answer so that I may tick it

Comment: Great. :) yup sure added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onClickListener for your each buttons (multiply, divide etc).

Also add a flag for each as,

```
 boolean multiply = false; //same for rest
```

which you will have to set to true when they are clicked like,

```
 case R.id.multiply:
    multiply = true;
```

then finally when you chck for onClick event of your = button

```
 public void onClick(View v){
     ..
     case R.id.buttonequals:
        if (multiply) {
           Multiplication();
        }

        else if (other flags) {
          Addition();
        }
       break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

set a same android:onClick for your all of your Buttons, For example: "clicking"

then use it like this:

```
public void clicking(View v) {
 Button button = (Button) v;
switch (button.getId()) {
case R.id.button0:

    text.setText(text.getText().toString()
            + btn0.getText().toString());

    break;

case R.id.button1:
    text.setText(text.getText().toString()
            + btn1.getText().toString());
    break;
and so on...
```